# Attempting to query a structure and extract certain values. Is there a way to do this without looping?

Tags: matlab

I have a structure of data with different columns of information. I would like to extract certain data pairs that agree with certain enforced conditions. For the sake of an example, considered the structure below titled Data. The structure has 5 fields. I would like to extract the pairs of Var_2 and Var_4 where Var_2 is less than 1 and Var_4 is less than 3.

```
Structure, "Data"               

Var_1   Var_2   Var_3   Var_4   Var_5
3.56    9.30    6.35    0.37    9.00
9.96   [0.91]   4.69   [2.55]   0.24
9.79    1.48    8.84    7.93    9.66
2.11   [0.03]   7.30   [1.49]   7.61
7.95    8.50    4.59    5.82    9.35
2.63    4.20    5.29    3.17    8.09
2.86    3.05    5.02    9.52    2.32
```

When querying the above structure, I would like to return a matrix containing only the relevant information.

ans = [0.91, 2.55; 0.03; 1.49]

How can I do this? Is there a way without looping?

Comment: See how to [*Access Data in a Structure*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-structure-array.html) and [*matrix indexing*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)

Comment: Great thanks. For some reason my mind wasn't clicking the first time I saw that. A second visit cleared things up.